# How to wait for a saga to finish calling an api to execute a next function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a question regarding the use of sagas.

I have a button that when clicked, triggers a function that calls an action:

**Component.js**

```
  onClickChainIdentifier = (event) => {
     //action called
      this.props.getChains();

     //next function to be called
      this.teste();
    }
  }
```

***Action.js***

```
export function getChains(){
  return {
    type: GET_CHAINS,
  }
}
```

When this action is dispatched, it fires a constant GET_CHAINS, which calls a saga:

**Saga.js**

```
export function* getAllChains() {
  const requestURL = process.env.PATH_API.GET_CHAINS;

  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGet, requestURL);
    yield put(getChainsSuccess(response));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(getChainsError(err));
  }
}


export default function* sagasApp() {

yield [
    fork( takeLatest, GET_CHAINS, getAllChains ),
  ]
}
```

I would like that after the api return (of success or error), I could call the **this.teste** function that is inside the component.
How do I make this happen?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: not familiar with Saga, but is the return type Promise? can't you use `.then` ?  `this.props.getChains().then(this.teste())`

Comment: No, because this don't return a promise. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: is `teste` async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a callback to your `getAllChains` function:

```
onClickChainIdentifier = (event) => {
   this.props.getChains(() => {
      this.teste();
   });
}


export function* getAllChains(callback) {
  const requestURL = process.env.PATH_API.GET_CHAINS;

  try {
    const response = yield call(requestGet, requestURL);
    yield put(getChainsSuccess(response));
    if (callback) { 
      callback(); 
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(getChainsError(err));
  }
}
```

Comment: Very good, Dario! The only thing I would add in your answer is to add the 'callback' parameter to action. ```export function getChains(callback){
  return {
    type: GET_CHAINS,
    callback
  }
}```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flags in order to control when and if your components should render. This is a common solution for rendering a fallback UI (e.g: a spinner or a text) in order to wait until an async process (saga, thunk, API service etc) is finished and the component has all it needs to render itself.

Check the solution I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613294/how-to-wait-for-complex-redux-saga-action-flow-to-finish-before-rendering-in-nex/55678196#55678196), you can visit this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2586j3k1p) which shows how you can use flags in order to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need to call a function after saga finished to execute.

Comment: Just for clarity, if you are planning to use redux in your app, you should mind keeping your functions pure. Otherwise, you will have unexpected behaviors and side effects which will be hard to debug as your app grows.

Answer (score 0):

As jank pointed out, you can test component's state in the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) and call a function when some condition is true. For example leveraging jank's example:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  if (this.props.pending && !prevProps.pending) {
    this.props.test()
  }
}
```

Will call `test` every time the `pending` prop is changed from `false` to `true`. The `test` function can have side effects like fetching from server or using some browser API. Same functionality can be achieved using the newer [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) of the Hooks API.